# Font-awesome codes overrided by toggle editor

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, font-awesome

I am editing an article and adding FontAwesome in it using Toggle Editor. I've found out that when I add the code using programmer view, it works fine. However, when I change to the designer view from the programmer view, the editor automatically edit the code like this:

Before:

[image]

After clicking "Toggle Editor":

[image]

It is quite inconvenient for me because I use the designer view to style the article frequently. Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Welcome on SO! Where were these screenshots taken: not in some tool provided by a Font-Awesome service, isn't it? Is this an a visual editor like Dreamweaver, a CMS editor (not WordPRess I guess)?

Comment: Oh, I have not mentioned the most important point. I am using Joomla 3 with JCK editor, thanks FelipeAls for reminding me :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to look into the allowed tags for the editor you're using.

In your case using JCK Editor - you can see [this article on why it removes certain code](http://www.joomlackeditor.com/component/content/article/166-why-does-some-html-get-removed-from-articles)

At first glance it appears there are whitelist & blacklists for some HTML.  You'll probably be able to add your selectors to the whitelist and they will no longer get stripped.

Comment: Thanks Hanny. I have checked that there is no Text Filter for Super User. However, I know that the editor loads class from the css. Quote start "The classes are extracted from your template stylesheet. They must exist in your template stylesheet to be displayed in the front-end." Quote end. However, I use "EASIEST: BootstrapCDN" method to include FontAwesome in my website. How to add the whole FontAwesome class to my template stylesheet?

Comment: I know sometimes even despite there being no text filter for super user, some components require you to go a step further and whitelist special tags or it cleans the HTML.  JCK does appear to be doing that in your case - I strongly recommend seeing if you can manually add your properties to the whitelist and see if that works (it should according to JCK); in terms of adding FontAwesome to your website, you should be able to just manually load the CSS to your CSS sheet on the backend to see if that will help it register as a tag to not be stripped.

Comment: If you want to get to where you can edit the CSS - you can either FTP in and get the CSS file from your template directory (probably in a CSS subdirectory) or go into the backend where you would edit the HTML, and you can edit the CSS page there.